# Does any warped product metric admit a function with hessian proportional to the metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[It is known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212697/what-does-it-mean-that-the-hessian-is-proportional-to-the-metric) that the existence of a function with hessian proportional to the metric implies that the metric is a warped product metric. Is the reciprocal true as well? I.e, if $(B \times N, g = g_B + h^2 g_N)$ is a warped product, do there always exist functions $\varphi, \psi$ such that $\nabla^2 \varphi = \psi g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  (With the caveat that if there is a function such that $\nabla^2\varphi = \psi g$, then necessarily it is a warped product over a *one-dimensional* base, so your question should really require $\dim B=1$.)

Consider the warped product $(B^1 \times N, g := dt^2 + h^2(t) g_N)$.
Let $f=f(t)$.
A direct computation shows that
$$ \nabla^2f = f^{\prime\prime}(t) dt^2 + (hh^\prime f^\prime)(t) g_N . $$
It follows that if $(\ln f^\prime)^\prime = (\ln h)^\prime$, then $\nabla^2f = f^{\prime\prime} g$.
The ODE is easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks! But why must the base be one-dimensional? I can't see the reason.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade in the accepted answer to the question you linked to, there is a reference. But here's a quick discussion. Suppose $\nabla^2\varphi = \psi g$, let $X = \nabla\varphi$ the gradient vector field, multiplying both sides by $X$ you find $\nabla_X X = \psi X$ and hence $X$ is geodesic. Let $Y,Z$ be such that $Y(\varphi) = Z(\varphi) = 0$, then $\langle \nabla_Y X,Z\rangle = \psi \langle Y,Z\rangle$ tells us that the level sets of $\varphi$ are totally umbilic. So unless $\psi = 0$ you cannot expect the base to have higher dimensions.

Comment: And when $\psi = 0$ the example of $\mathbb{R}^n$ shows that it can _also_ be a warped product over a higher dimensional base, but it is still definitely a warped product over a one dimensional base.

Comment: @WillieWong thanks! But it's been a long day for me and I'm still having some trouble putting your arguments together. It's probably obvious but I don't see why the level sets being totally umbilical in addition to the gradient vector field being geodesic implies the base is one-dimensional. I did try looking up the references in that link but it hasn't helped me.

Comment: The above is not a full proof; it is an argument providing a moral justification. The key is that the base manifold embeds as a totally geodesic submanifold of the warped product. So even if the level sets of $\varphi$ factor, the fact that these leaves have extrinsic curvature indicates that you cannot group part of it together into the base.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: @MatheusAndrade I posted a full proof of the warped product decomposition at the other question. Hopefully that helps you.

Comment: @WillieWong it does. Thanks again!